# akka actor child troubles

Tags: akka, akka-actor

I am realy surprised by this case. Have any body any thoughts why this happen?

this works fine each time:

```
child(name) match {
  case Some(ref) => ref ! Ping
  case _ =>
    val ref = actorOf(PingActor.props, name)
    ref ! Ping
}
```

We are create actor if child is not exist.
And then send Ping message.

This sometime hangs up on case of actor already exist:

```
child(name) getOrElse actorOf(PingActor.props, name) ! GetState
```

Why?

Comment: `hangs up`... you mean something freezes?

Comment: yes, freeze when sending message

Comment: how do you know it freezes when sending the message, and not when calling `getOrElse` ?

Comment: i know only one thing - actor freezes on this string where getOrElse
when i changed it to match - it started work well

Comment: I get from the accepted answer that it was not about anything freezing, just about a message not being sent. You will get better answers faster by giving a more accurate description of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

Because of operator precedence your message is sent only when `child(name)` returns `None`, i.e. `getOrElse` is invoked.

Use non-infix method invocation to avoid this:

```
child(name).getOrElse(actorOf(PingActor.props, name)) ! GetState
```

**Long answer**

As per [Scala language specification](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/06-expressions.html#infix-operations), normally infix operations in Scala are left-associative, and are evaluated from left to right. If that was the case here your code would work fine.

However there are also operator precedence rules which allow usual mathematical and logic operations without parenthesis. According to them, `!` operator has higher precedence than `getOrElse` and is evaluated prior to it, thus sending message from 'inside'.